# QFileDialog: how to set default filename in "Save as..." dialog

Tags: macos, qt4, qfiledialog

I try to create "Save as..." dialog in Mac OS X. But I don't want to use `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName()` function, because dialog that created by this function is **NOT** truly-native in Mac OS X Lion. So I decide to create dialog as `QFileDialog` object:

```
auto export_dialog( new QFileDialog( main_window ) );
export_dialog->setWindowModality( Qt::WindowModal );
export_dialog->setFileMode( QFileDialog::AnyFile );
export_dialog->setAcceptMode( QFileDialog::AcceptSave );
```

All works fine, except one problem. I cannot set default name for saved file, so user must type this name manually every time. I know that function `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName()` allows to set default filename via third argument, *dir* (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName). But how to set this default name without this function?

I can set default suffix for saved file via `QFileDialog::setDefaultSuffix()` function, but I need to set whole default name, not only default suffix.

I've tried to use `QFileDialog::setDirectory()` function, but it sets only directory where to save, without name of saved file.

I use Qt 4.8.1 on Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: I found it here: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/49434-QFileDialog-set-default-name?highlight=QFileDialog.

Answer (score 16):

I have found that using **`selectFile("myFileName");`** only works if the file actually exists.  In my case, the intent is to create a new file with the option of overwriting an existing file.

The solution that worked for me *(Qt 5.3.2)* was as follows:

```
QFileDialog svDlg;

QString saveFileName = svDlg.getSaveFileName(this, caption, preferredName, filter);
```

In the above example, preferredName is a QString that contains "C:/pre-selected-name.txt"

Comment: (the `preferredName` argument corresponds to the `dir` parameter. [Official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName): "If *dir* includes a file name, the file will be selected.".

Answer (score 7):

Restating what was in the comments for future visitors, the following line puts "myFileName" as the default name in the QFileDialog:

```
export_dialog->selectFile("myFileName");
```

Discussion: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/49434-QFileDialog-set-default-name?highlight=QFileDialog

Not-so-helpful docs: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#selectFile

Answer (score 3):

```
QString dir = QDir::homePath();
QString name = "test.txt";

QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(nullptr, tr("save file"), dir + "/" + name, tr("TXT (*.txt)"));
```

If you set "dir" argument, and dir is "file"(exist or not), in windows you will have default name.

Comment: Does this work on windows (where the path separator is `"\\"`?

Answer (score 1):

With the current QT-version (5.x) you can set your preferred file-name with the argument `directory` in the [`QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName) function call:

```
QFileDialog.getSaveFileName( directory = 'preferredFileName.txt' )
```

docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName